# Remove element, replace element elsewhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and would like to simply move an element when it is clicked to another div. How is the best way to do this?

```
<div ng-app>
    <h1>First area</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="elem in elems">
            {{ elem.elem_name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Second Area</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So given the example in my JS file how would I make it so when I click an `elem` it leaves the first area and appears in the second area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `selected` property to each item and toggle it when it's clicked. Use a `filter` to filter each list based on `selected`...

```
$scope.items = [{name: "foo", selected: false},
                {name: "bar", selected: false},
                {name: "baz", selected: false},
                {name: "quux", selected: false}];

$scope.move = function(item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
};
```

View

```
List 1
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : {selected: false}">
    {{ item.name }}
    <a href="#" ng-click="move(item)">move</a>
  </li>
</ul>

List 2
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : {selected: true}">
    {{ item.name }}
    <a href="#" ng-click="move(item)">move</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JsBin: http://jsbin.com/sawotuza/1/edit?html,js,output**

Answer (score 2):

I know little about Angular.js but I'd be surprised if the way to do this did not involve adding a new set of elements just for the "Second area" like so:

```
<h1>Second Area</h1>
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="elem in secondElems">
         {{ elem.elem_name }}
     </li>
</ul>
```

And then programatically removing the clicked element from `elems` and putting it in `secondElems`.

Comment: When moving a DOM element, there is no need to remove it first, assigning it to the new location automatically removes it from its current location, e.g. [*insertBefore*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727): `If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed`.

Comment: What urig described is a correct way of dealing with this in Angular, where you're moving items from one array to another. There is no direct DOM manipulation, databinding takes care of that.